# Light Sensor INT Pin function

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, current, i2c, light-sensor

I have a [Light Sensor IC](https://www.vishay.com/docs/84366/veml6030.pdf).

There is an Interrupt pin. I can see the status of it on page 9.

What is the high and low threshold exceed that they are mentioning in that table? Can someone tell me what does the interrupt pin indicate when connected to a Microcontroller GPIO?

Is there a possibility that the INT Pin will send some signal if there's some error in I2C Communication bits? Like does INT help in the data protection of the data transferred from the Light sensor to the microcontroller?

Comment: scroll up to page 8. You see registers setting thresholds (low and high) and such. And even higher on page 5 you have the graphs with all the wavelengths and sensitivity and stuff.

Comment: From the datasheet: '_For detailed description about set-up and use of the interrupt as well as more application related information see AN: “Designing VEML6030
into an Application”_'

Comment: INT for initiating communication by sensor. The values and procedures can be programmed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Int is an interrupt output.

It is configurable to be pulled down (it needs a pull-up resistor since it is an open drain output) when programmed thresholds are crossed. The threshold is on the ambient light since it is the measured variable.

It is used to launch an event driven communication instead of polling consecutive reads by the micro-controller.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Just a question. Actually, we have a pull-up resistor at INT. How to program this IC? Are we programming and setting the ambient light information through the I2C Lines?

Comment: @Newbie yes the configuration is done through the I2C. You have 7 registers (6 used and one unimplemented). To change a register you set the address which is depending on pin 4 either 0x48 (pin 4 high) or 0x10 (pin 4 low), write the register number, LSB of the value you want to write to register and then MSB of the value you want to write to register.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer